# backgroundImage carousel: Why wont my react.js array of local images render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, carousel

I'm adding an image carousel to my website. The div that is linked to carousel.js is totally blank. It seems that the images are not rendering. My images are local and stored in an array in carousel.js. I've gone through similar threads but haven't been able to get the images to render. For example, I've made the image size smaller, tried importing the images at the top of carousel.js, moved the images folder to the public folder generated by node module, and about ten other things. This is my first react project so any help would be appreciated.

The full project can be viewed on cloud 9 [here](https://preview.c9users.io/miagenovese/lucky-cup-coffee-chop)

Here's my carousel.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


const imgUrls = [
  "./images/croissant.jpg",
  "./images/herbal-tea.jpg",
  "./images/matcha-latte.jpg",
  "./images/mochaLatte.jpg",
  "./images/waffle.jpg"
  ];

class Carousel extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            currentImageIndex: 0
        };

        this.nextSlide = this.nextSlide.bind(this);
        this.previousSlide = this.previousSlide.bind(this);
    }

    previousSlide () {
        const lastIndex = imgUrls.length - 1;
        const { currentImageIndex } = this.state;
        const shouldResetIndex = currentImageIndex === 0;
        const index =  shouldResetIndex ? lastIndex : currentImageIndex - 1;

        this.setState({
            currentImageIndex: index
        });
    }

    nextSlide () {
        const lastIndex = imgUrls.length - 1;
        const { currentImageIndex } = this.state;
        const shouldResetIndex = currentImageIndex === lastIndex;
        const index =  shouldResetIndex ? 0 : currentImageIndex + 1;

        this.setState({
            currentImageIndex: index
        });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className="carousel">
                <Arrow direction="left" clickFunction={ this.previousSlide } glyph="&#9664;" />
                <ImageSlide url={ imgUrls[this.state.currentImageIndex] } />
                <Arrow direction="right" clickFunction={ this.nextSlide } glyph="&#9654;" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const Arrow = ({ direction, clickFunction, glyph }) => (
    <div 
        className={ `slide-arrow ${direction}` } 
        onClick={ clickFunction }>
        { glyph } 
    </div>
);

const ImageSlide = ({ url }) => {
    const styles = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${url})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundPosition: 'center'
    };

    return (
        <div className="image-slide" style={styles}></div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Carousel />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? I think this is a webpack configuration issue.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` for carousel.js

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 428 (Precondition Required)`

Comment: `Error: EDISCONNECT: client connection went away
    at module.exports.ReliableSocket.disconnect (workspace-html5.js:43980)
    at workspace-html5.js:43964
    at wrapped (workspace-html5.js:7447)`

Comment: In your images array I think you need `require("./images/croissant.jpg") `

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack you need to use `require('./imagedirectory')`

So it is like this...

`const imgUrls = [ require("./images/croissant.jpg") , require("./images/herbal-tea.jpg") , require("./images/matcha-latte.jpg") , require("./images/mochaLatte.jpg") , require("./images/waffle.jpg") ];`

Comment: I made the changes but they're still not rendering. I'm not aware that I'm using webpack, I've never used it before but I can look into it

Comment: I get the same Uncaught Syntax error plus these two: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
workspace-html5.js:228 warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. " + eventList.length + " listeners of type "setPath" added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.`

Comment: Hmm, I think this is server issue. Can you comment out all variables in the carousel component and just render `render() {return(<div>carousel page</div>)} ` to test that its not an issue with images files.

Comment: Ok, tried that and now this is the only error message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: It says carousel.js:1

Comment: Try `export default class Carousel extends React.Component`

Comment: I'm not sure how created the project, but in terminal do this `npm install babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react --save-dev` since its not recognising the import maybe you are missing `babel`

Comment: No luck, I'm considering starting over from scratch with webpack

Comment: I see what you did wrong by looking at your project folder, your directory is all wrong. You have carousel.js outside of react folder. The react stuff happens in `lucky-cup-coffee-shop` folder not outside of it

Comment: I think I've fixed the directory, but still it's not rendering. The script.js Google maps API is rendering just fine

Comment: Can you update question to include the new directory paths

Comment: It's still incorrect. I'll create a react js app and add your files correctly. I'll update you with the correct project directory

Comment: Done check it here https://github.com/sghaleb1/lucky-cup-coffee-chop . You will need to download it, then go inside `lucky-cup-coffee-chop` folder and type `yarn install` then `yarn start` Everything works. But the problem is if you are gonna use use `react` then i suggest changing your layout. Right now you have everything in `index.html` but with `react` you can make a component of each section. I could of made some changes to restructure it. But it would take more time. Maybe a day.

Comment: I will try what you suggested. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

```
const ImageSlide = ({ url }) => {

    const img = require(`${url}`);

    const styles = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${img})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundPosition: 'center'
    };

    return (
        <div className="image-slide" style={styles}></div>
    );
}
```

Comment: It is working using my test with "create-react-app". Do you have any error log ?

Comment: Yes here are the errors `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` , `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` , `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()` , `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 499 (unknown)`